# GraphQL Mongoose with MongoDB Atlas return empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql, apollo-server, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect MongoDB Atlas and mongoose but server always returns an empty array '[ ]'. When I load a mock data everything works (Mocked data and MongoDB Atlas have the same values)
I have **connect** to MongoDB Atlas, but can't get some data.

Controller:

```
const express = require('express')
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express')
const { createServer } = require('http')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const typeDefs = require('./schema')
const resolvers = require('./resolvers')

const app = express()
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    playground: {
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
        settings: {
            'editor.theme': 'light'
        }
    }
})
server.applyMiddleware({ app })

const httpServer = createServer(app)
server.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer)

mongoose
    .connect(`mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.brdqp.mongodb.net/${process.env.mongoDatabase}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then((res) => {
        httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log('connected!')
        })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error while connecting to MongoDB', err);
    })
```

Schema:

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server-express')

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Todo {
        _id: String,
        title: String,
        description: String
        status: String
        date: String
    }

    type Query {
        todos: [Todo]
    }

`
module.exports = typeDefs
```

Resolvers:

```
const { Todo, Restaurant, Customer, Order } = require('./models')
const pubsub = require('./pubsub')

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        todos(parent, args, context, info) {
            return Todo.find()
                .then(todo => {
                    return todo.map(r => ({ ...r._doc }))
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error(err)
                })
        },
    },
}

module.exports = resolvers
```

**MongoDB Atlas** collection: (Database name : node, collection name in DB : todo)

```
_id : 5c9bdb721c9d440000345d62
title : "question"
desctiption : "test test"
status: done
date: 1
```

But the **server** **always** returns [ ]
How???? Why&?

Comment: get and log data before return

Comment: To clarify the above comment, add `console.log` inside your resolvers in some places, to figure out what's actually getting called and returned. Don't return anything until you've logged what it would be. This is how you will find out why you might not be returning what you think you should be.